# Where to see the output data send by publisher?

Tags: c++, ros, robotics

I am doing a program on ROS, in which the publisher is subscriber's callback function and all are going well except only thing that I can't see where the data is getting print.

The code I wrote is shown below:

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

    class pubsub
    {
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        ros::Publisher pub;
        ros::Subscriber sub;

    public:
        void callback(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& msg) 
        {
            ROS_INFO("I heard this data: [%d]", msg->data);
            std_msgs::Int16 msg2;
            msg2.data = msg->data;
            ROS_INFO_STREAM(" I got some data");
            pub.publish(msg2);
        }

        pubsub()
        {
            pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int16>("just",100);
            sub = nh.subscribe<std_msgs::Int16>("just",100,&pubsub::callback,this);
        }
    };



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc,argv,"node");
    pubsub ps;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

Program is compiling properly. When executes, only waits for data and is not giving any output to terminal.

The command **rostopic echo /just** shows nothing even though I enters integer after running the code.

Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

callback will never be called because publisher is inside the callback.
In fact you are not publishing anything. Please publish initial message from main or from constructor, then you will get the message loop you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Like already described in nayab's answer, you are publishing a message if a message was received. Because no messages at this topic are sent, you are never sending a message. You need to publish the message somwhere else to receive it instead. Therefore just add a new method like `pub` to your `pubsub` class. Inside the `main` loop with a `ros::rate` with 10 Hz for example. Don't forget to add `ros::spinOnce()` to allow callback handling. Here is the improved code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

class pubsub
{
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    ros::Subscriber sub;

public:
    void callback(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& msg) 
    {
        ROS_INFO("I heard this data: [%d]", msg->data);
    }

    void pub(int number)
    {
        std_msgs::Int16 msg;
        msg.data = number;
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Publishing data");
        pub.publish(msg);
    }

    pubsub()
    {
        pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int16>("just",100);
        sub = nh.subscribe<std_msgs::Int16>("just",100,&pubsub::callback,this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"node");
    pubsub ps;

    ros::Rate r(10);
    int number = 0;
    while (ros::ok())
    {
       ps.pub(number++);
       ros::spinOnce();
       r.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

class pubsub
{
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    ros::Subscriber sub;

public:
    void callback(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& msg) 
    {
        ROS_INFO("I heard this data: [%d]", msg->data);
    }

    void pub(int number)
    {
        std_msgs::Int16 msg;
        msg.data = number;
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Publishing data");
        pub.publish(msg);
    }

    pubsub()
    {
        pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int16>("just",100);
        sub = nh.subscribe<std_msgs::Int16>("just",100,&pubsub::callback,this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"node");
    pubsub ps;

    ros::Rate r(10);
    int number = 0;
    while (ros::ok())
    {
       ps.pub(number++);
       ros::spinOnce();
       r.sleep();
    }

    return 0;`ahah sala...`enter code here`
}
```